# How do you overload an operator in swift?

Tags: swift, operator-overloading, operators

Say you have a class C. It has two instance variables, number and vector. vector is just an array of either ints or doubles.

I would like to do the following:

```
c1 = C()
c1.number = 2
c1.vector = [1,2,3]
c2 = C()
c2.number = 3 
c2.vector = [4,6,7]

println(c1.number + c2.number) \\print to screen 5
println(c1.vector + c2.vector) \\ print [5,8,10]
```

Basically, I'm looking to overload the "+" operator so that it knows which "version" of the "+" to use depending of the type.

Comment: I guess one `+` is already defined (int+int). Just declare an infix operator for `Vector` as described in the Swift handbook p.479

Comment: See the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID42

Comment: sorry, I updated my question. Vector isn't a class. It's just an array of Type T, which is to say it is just an array of either ints or doubles.

Comment: Why not just overload the operator for `C`? `func +(lhs: C, rhs: C) -> C {...}`?

Comment: And if you follow @mattt's advice, you should be able to `println((c1 + c2).vector)` if you really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The + operator is already defined for the type Array. It does an array merge and tacks the values of the rvalue onto the lvalue. To do a sum of values by index you can do something like this:

```
protocol Numeric { }

extension Double: Numeric {}
extension Int: Numeric {}

func +<T: Numeric>(left: [T], right: [T]) -> [T]? {
    var numElements: Int = 0

    if count(left) != count(right) {
        return nil
    } else {
        numElements = count(left)
    }

    var result = [T]()

    for var i = 0; i < numElements; ++i {
        if let lvalue = left[i] as? Int, rvalue = right[i] as? Int {
            result.append(lvalue + rvalue as! T)
        } else if let lvalue = left[i] as? Double, rvalue = right[i] as? Double {
            result.append(lvalue + rvalue as! T)
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

But generally, I wouldn't advise overriding a predefined operator because of the high potential to cause confusion and chaos later on down the road.